# How can we check if the json is nested or not?

Tags: c#, json, api

I saw in another post someone identifying if json is nested or not if it contains a second object after the first then it will return true if not false, in JavaScript

Here is their method. Can we achieve this using C#

```
function check_if_nested(obj) {
    check_nest=[]
    obj.map(function(e,i) {$.each(e, function(v){
      if(typeof(obj[0][v])=='object') {check_nest.push('nested')} else {check_nest.push('not nested')}
    })})
    if(check_nest.includes('nested')) {return(true)} else {return(false)}
    }


//Not nested

obj_1 = [{
    one: "apples",
    two: "oranges"
}]



Usage: check_if_nested(obj_1)

output: false


obj_2 = [{
    one: "apples",
    two: "oranges",
    children: [{
        three: "bananas",
        four: "jicamas"
    }]
}]

output: true
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var nested = jObject.Children().Any(x => x.Children().Any(y => y.HasValues));

// or maybe a little easier to read

var nested = JObject.Parse(json)
                    .Values()
                    .Any(x => x.HasValues);
```

<sub>***Disclaimer** : This is completely untested and as such I absolve myself of any responsible for the people you maim or otherwise harm with this code*</sub>

**Update**

```
var token = JToken.Parse(asd2);
bool result;
if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
   result = token.Children().Any(x => x.Values().Any(y => y.HasValues));
else
   result =token.Values().Any(x => x.HasValues);
```

Comment: Thanks @TheGeneral . Sometimes I am also getting an Array.. Should I put an if condition and use JArray.Parse.. and If i can how to check the second of that

Comment: something like this I have but not show how to check Json Array second property.. I have updated the question

Comment: @KevinDavis965 OK I'll have a look for you

Comment: @KevinDavis965 updated, see if this is working for you